# haskell two parsers for one text

Tags: parsing, haskell

I have got a text with two separated form of a text e.g:
    123:ABC
    456:DEF
    ABC:123
    386:HDG
    DEF:456

Now I wrote two parsers, first one for 123:ABC, this form and the other for ABC:456. What I want to know is how can I make two parsers in one main function

```
123:ABC
456:DEF
ABC:123
386:HDG
DEF:456 

aa=B.readFile logFile >>= print . parseOnly aaParser
bb=B.readFile logFile >>= print . parseOnly bbParser

main :: IO ()
main =B.readFile logFile >>= print . parseOnly aaParser --there is missing the aaparser and I need both of them for the text above
```

Comment: The problem is now to combine two parsers into one main function, it's to combine two parsers into one parser. I imagine you want either `aaParser` to match or your `bbParser`. It looks like the attoParsec way to match either of two parsers with backtracking is `eitherP`.  What are your `aaParser` and `bbParser`? I suspect they parse the entire file, and thus can't be combined directly, since it looks like you want to match one pattern or the other for each line, not for the entire file.

Comment: My aaparser parses AAA:123 and bbparser 123:AAA in my text both types are mixed so i need to combine both parsers to one.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to tell from your implementation what the form of output of the parsers is so its very difficult to know how they might be combined. One possible way is to make each of the two different formats correspond to a different Data Constructors for an algebraic data type. A simple solution might look something like this:

```
module TinyParse(parseABC123Format) where

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char

data TwoTypes
    = ABCNums String String
    | NumsABC String String
    deriving (Eq, Show)

parseABC123Format :: String -> [TwoTypes]
parseABC123Format str = case parse parseABC123File "ABC123" str of
    Left err -> error $ show err
    Right p -> p

parseABC123File :: Parser [TwoTypes]
parseABC123File = endBy parseEither spaces

parseEither :: Parser TwoTypes
parseEither = parseABC123 <|> parse123ABC

parseABC123 :: Parser TwoTypes
parseABC123 = do
    threeLetters <- parseABC
    semi <- char ':'
    threeNumbers <- parseNums
    return $ ABCNums threeLetters threeNumbers

parse123ABC :: Parser TwoTypes
parse123ABC = do
    threeNumbers <- parseNums
    semi <- char ':'
    threeLetters <- parseABC
    return $ NumsABC threeNumbers threeLetters

parseNums :: Parser String
parseNums = do
    d1 <- digit
    d2 <- digit
    d3 <- digit
    return (d1:d2:d3:[])

parseABC :: Parser String
parseABC = do
    l1 <- upper
    l2 <- upper
    l3 <- upper
    return (l1:l2:l3:[])
```

Comment: A Hayoo! http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html search for `parseOnly` suggest the OP is using attoparsec https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec.

Comment: it isn't working,the problem is i can't combine two parser for one file.